# Logitech c920 (video) recently stopped working in Cheese

Tags: 17.10, skype, cheese

It worked some weeks ago. Ubuntu 17.10 x64 up to date.
Microphone works but when I start Cheese I get "error reading video from webcam" (Translated from french)
It is also not working in Skypeforlinux(8.15.0.4) and the microphone works.

I installed VLC and everything works well in VLC.

Is this a knowned bug?

Answer (score 1):

Cheese 3.28.0-1 Archlinux and Logitech, Inc. HD Pro Webcam C920. The camera can be loaded in VLC with *Open Capture Device* → `/dev/video0`. This problem seems to be [this bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=795022).

`lsusb` reports:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:082d Logitech, Inc. HD Pro Webcam C920
```

The solution:

```
sudo systemctl --global disable pipewire.socket
```

Afterwards, reboot.

[image: cheese working]